# JQuery's on(): How do I make JQuery find the selectors from left to right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery finds the elements matched by the selectors from right to left. Normally, if I want to select from left to right, I do something like this: `$('#context').find('a')`

I'm using `on()` to call event handlers for dynamically generated elements, like so: `$(document).on('click','#context a',function(){})`. `#context` is loaded dynamically. How do I select from left to right in this case?

Comment: Why not `$('#context').on('click','a',function(){})`?

Comment: #context is also loaded dynamically.

Comment: What would be the benefit of going left to right in this case? it's not like it uses optimized methods in this case.

Comment: Just select a wrapper higher in the DOM which is not dynamically generated. Also, a class on the links won't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no benefit to going left to right vs right to left with event delegation because you're really only testing whether or not a single element matches a selector. For example, the following would be equivalent to the code in your question:

```
$(document).on("click",function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is("#context a")) {
        // do something
    }
})
```

the selector working left to right vs right to left wouldn't have any performance benefit here. Of course, you could still do it if you wanted to:

```
$(document).on("click",function(e){
    if ($("#context").find("a").filter(function(){
        return this == e.target;
    }).length) {
        // do something
    }
})
```

then, you have to take into account that this is optimized in newer browsers to  use [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches)

```
$(document).on("click",function(e){
    if (e.target.matches("#context a")) {
        // do something
    }
})
// note, Element.matches is only supported in chrome 34, all 
// other browsers require a vendor prefix at this time
// (which jquery takes care of)
```